# Flask + sqlalchemy advanced logging

Tags: python, logging, flask, sqlalchemy, werkzeug

I found a few other posts on this but none that worked for me yet so I wanted to reach out and see if anyone could explain how to properly get / redirect / set handlers on some of the loggers present in Flask / Werkzeurg / sqlalchemy.

Research prior that could not answer my question:

https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/1359

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/logging/

https://gist.github.com/ibeex/3257877

My configurations:

main.py

```
    ...

    def init_app():
    """ Runs prior to app launching, contains initialization code """

    # set logging level
    if not os.path.exists(settings.LOG_DIR):
        os.makedirs(settings.LOG_DIR)

    # default level
    log_level = logging.CRITICAL

    if settings.ENV == 'DEV':
        log_level = logging.DEBUG
    elif settings.ENV == 'TEST':
        log_level = logging.WARNING
    elif settings.ENV == 'PROD':
        log_level = logging.ERROR

    log_formatter = logging.Formatter("[%(asctime)s] {%(pathname)s:%(lineno)d} %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
    api_logger = logging.getLogger()
    api_handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(
            settings.API_LOG_FILE,
            when='midnight',
            backupCount=10
        )
    api_handler.setLevel(log_level)
    api_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)
    api_logger.addHandler(api_handler)
    logging.getLogger('werkzeug').addHandler(api_handler)


    db_logger = logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy')
    db_handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(
            settings.DB_LOG_FILE,
            when='midnight',
            backupCount=10
        )
    db_handler.setLevel(log_level)
    db_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)
    db_logger.addHandler(db_handler)
    logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine').addHandler(db_handler)
    logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.dialects').addHandler(db_handler)
    logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.pool').addHandler(db_handler)
    logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.orm').addHandler(db_handler)



# add endpoints

...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    init_app()
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=7777)
```

I tried grabbing and changes settings on the loggers a few different ways but I still end up with the werkzeug debug outputting to console and not my logs, I can see the logs are being created but it doesn't look like the loggers are actually outputting to them:

api.log (formatter wrote to it)

```
2018-02-15 12:03:03,944] {/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/werkzeug/_internal.py:88} WARNING -  * Debugger is active!
```

db.log (empty)

Any insight on this would be much appreciated!

**UPDATE**

I was able to get the werkzeug logger working using the long hand version, it seems the shorthand function calls shown were returning null objects. The sqlalchemy logger is still outputting to console though.. Could the engine configuration be overriding my filehandler?

## main.py

```
...

# close current file handlers
for handler in copy(logging.getLogger().handlers):
    logging.getLogger().removeHandler(handler)
    handler.close()
for handler in copy(logging.getLogger('werkzeug').handlers):
    logging.getLogger('werkzeug').removeHandler(handler)
    handler.close()
for handler in copy(logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine').handlers):
    logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine').removeHandler(handler)
    handler.close()
for handler in copy(logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.dialects').handlers):
    logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.dialects').removeHandler(handler)
    handler.close()
for handler in copy(logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.pool').handlers):
    logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.pool').removeHandler(handler)
    handler.close()
for handler in copy(logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.orm').handlers):
    logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.orm').removeHandler(handler)
    handler.close()


# create our own custom handlers
log_formatter = logging.Formatter("[%(asctime)s] {%(pathname)s:%(lineno)d} %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
api_handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(
        settings.API_LOG_FILE,
        when='midnight',
        backupCount=10
    )
api_handler.setLevel(log_level)
api_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)
logging.getLogger().setLevel(log_level)
logging.getLogger().addHandler(api_handler)
logging.getLogger('werkzeug').setLevel(log_level)
logging.getLogger('werkzeug').addHandler(api_handler)


db_handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(
        settings.DB_LOG_FILE,
        when='midnight',
        backupCount=10
    )
db_handler.setLevel(log_level)
db_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine').addHandler(db_handler)
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine').setLevel(log_level)
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.dialects').addHandler(db_handler)
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.dialects').setLevel(log_level)
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.pool').addHandler(db_handler)
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.pool').setLevel(log_level)
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.orm').addHandler(db_handler)
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.orm').setLevel(log_level)
```

## database.py

```
...
engine = create_engine(getDBURI(), echo="debug", echo_pool=True, pool_recycle=10)
```

*ANSWER*

For future reference if anyone runs into this issue, sqlalchemy engine configuration `echo=True|'debug'` will OVERRIDE your loggers. Fixed the issue by changing my engine configuration to:

```
engine = create_engine(getDBURI(), echo_pool=True, pool_recycle=10)
```

And then everything worked like a charm. Cheers! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as i understand it your file based log configuration for werkzeug is actually working => it outputs into api.log

The db log handler is also working (file gets created etc.) but there is no output.
This is probably due to the loglevel of those loggers beeing on Error by default. You need to set them manually on a lower level like this:

```
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.dialects').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.pool').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.orm').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

That werkzeug is still outputting to console is probably because there is allways a root logger defined. Before you add your new handlers you should do the following to remove all log handlers:

```
    for handler in copy(logging.getLogger().handlers):
        logging.getLogger().removeHandler(handler)
        handler.close()  # clean up used file handles
```

Then you can also assign your app log handler as the root log handler with

```
logging.getLogger().addHandler(api_handler)
```

If its not the root logger but just the werkzeug logger which has a default console logger defined you can also just remove all handlers from the werkzeug logger before adding yours like this:

```
    for handler in copy(logging.getLogger('werkzeug').handlers):
        logging.getLogger('werkzeug').removeHandler(handler)
        handler.close()  # clean up used file handles
    logging.getLogger('werkzeug').addHandler(api_handler)
```

Comment: that was very helpful @quantumbyte could you explain the difference between setting the logging level on the handler and the logger? I think thats where my confusion is

Comment: Hi Tyler, great that it helped. The difference is that while the logger Level controls what log messages lets say a module (you can have a different logger for a differnt module/package etc.) can emmit the handler is much more powerful and controls what is beeing sent to your log message target. This becomes useful if you want to send different levels to different targets. Lets say critical should go to a Central Logging System while at the same time everything gets logged locally to a file. In the end its multiple filtering steps: log message => logger filter => handler filter => target

Comment: Very informative, Python usually works at a higher level-logic so some of the implementation is clouded without digging through the module src, glad you could put it in simpler terms, thanks 100!