# How to make SQLAlchemy and Flask use the same logger?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

probably I don't quite understand how logging really works in Python. I'm trying to debug a Flask+SQLAlchemy (but without flask_sqlalchemy) app which mysteriously hangs on some queries only if run from within Apache, so I need to have proper logging to get meaningful information. The Flask application by default comes with a nice logger+handler, but how do I get SQLAlchemy to use the same logger?

The "Configuring Logging" section in the SQLAlchemy just explains how to turn on logging in general, but not how to "connect" SQLAlchemy's logging output to an already existing logger.

I've been looking at [Flask + sqlalchemy advanced logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48812971/flask-sqlalchemy-advanced-logging) for a while with a blank, expressionless face. I have no idea if the answer to my question is even in there.

EDIT: Thanks to the answer given I now know that I can have two loggers use the same handler. Now of course my apache error log is littered with hundreds of lines of echoed SQL calls. I'd like to log only error messages to the httpd log and divert all lower-level stuff to a separate logfile. See the code below. However, I still get every debug message into the http log. Why?

```
if app.config['DEBUG']:
    # Make logger accept all log levels
    app.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    for h in app.logger.handlers:
        # restrict logging to /var/log/httpd/error_log to errors only
        h.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    if app.config['LOGFILE']:
        # configure debug logging only if logfile is set
        debug_handler = logging.FileHandler(app.config['LOGFILE'])
        debug_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        app.logger.addHandler(debug_handler)
        # get logger for SQLAlchemy
        sq_log = logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine')
        sq_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        # remove any preconfigured handlers there might be
        for h in sq_log.handlers:
            sq_log.removeHandler(h)
            h.close()
        # Now, SQLAlchemy should not have any handlers at all. Let's add one
        # for the logfile
        sq_log.addHandler(debug_handler)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot `make SQLAlchemy and Flask use the same logger`, but you can make them writing to one place by add a common Handler. And maybe this article is helpful: https://www.electricmonk.nl/log/2017/08/06/understanding-pythons-logging-module/

By the way, if you want to get all logs in one single request, you can set a uniq name for current thread before request, and add the `threadName` in you logging's formatter.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my question at EDIT: I still had "echo=True" set on the create_engine, so what I saw was all the additional output on stderr. echo=False stops that but still logs to debug level DEBUG.

Answer (score 0):

Clear all corresponding handlers created by SqlAlchemy:

```
logging.getLogger("sqlalchemy.engine.Engine").handlers.clear()
```

The code above should be called after engine created.